# Union N of a finite number of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I understand the maths here but I am struggling with the intuition. I have proved it to be true for N=3 events, both pictorially with a Venn diagram but also in mathematical proof.

When looking at N events the event is proved by induction, which confuses me and the result is as follows:

Why do we subtract the sum of the probabilities of the intersections of all possible groups of four of the events?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where $n=2$, we subtract the probability of $A_1\cap A_2$ because the probability of this part is computed twice. When $n=3$, we add back the probability of $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3$ because we subtract the probability of this part $C^3_2$ times and add it $C^1_3$ times. The same is true for all $n\geq 4$. For example, $n=4$, to keep the probabilities of all possible groups of less than 4 events are true, we calculate $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4$ for $C^1_4-C^2_4+C^3_4=2$ times, hence we subtract it. In general, $\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}C^i_n=1$ and for $n$, when we consider event $\cap_{i=1}^mA_i,\ m<n$, just focus on the events $\{A_i: i=1,2,...,m\}$.

Comment: Hi M.Shang, could you explain for the scenario when n =4 or more. For three or more I understand but for higher level cases I am confused

Comment: Hi Andrew, let's consider the case $n=4$, we like to consider all events $A_i, i\in{1,2,3,4}$, hence we get $\sum_{i=1}^4P(A_i)$. However, we will calculate the probability of $A_i\cap A_j, i<j, I,j=1,2,3,4$ twice, that's why we subtract $\sum_{i<j}A_i\cap A_j$. Focus on $A_1,A_2,A_3$, we have calculated $A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3$ for $C^1_3-C^2_3=0$ times, hence add it back. Now for $A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3\cap A_4$, we add the probability for $C^1_4$ times in the first step, subtract the probability for $C^2_4$ times in the second step, add again for $C^3_4$ times in the third step.

Comment: Finally, we calculate $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4$ for $2$ times, hence subtract it. For larger number, the equation I mentioned works. I hope this can help.